# Find a unitary matrix $P$ so that $P^{\ast} A P$ is diagonal, when $A= \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a unitary matrix $P$ so that $P^{\ast} A P$ is diagonal, when $A= \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 1  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

I found the characteristic polynomial $\lambda(\lambda-2)$, computed the eigenvalues $\lambda=0,2$, and found the corresponding eigenspaces $\text{span} \left(\begin{smallmatrix} i \\  1  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\text{span} \left(\begin{smallmatrix} -i \\  1  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. I then normalized both vectors in the basis to get the vectors $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, which I combined into a matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Question: Can the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ be $P$?

Comment: If you calculate $P^{\ast} A P$, are you getting a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Well, is it unitary? Does $P^*AP$ produce a diagonal matrix?

Comment: you should work first on representing (modulus $1$) complex numbers by 2D rotations matrix, such that the multiplication of complex numbers becomes the multiplication of matrices

Comment: $P^{\ast}AP$ doesn't seem to be diagonal, so I guess it's not the right one. I'm not really sure where I made the mistake though...